# "Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed" while trying to use a bootable usb

Tags: usb, live-usb, initramfs

I'm trying to make a bootable USB. But when I start start Ubuntu, this error message comes up:

```
Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
```

Then the wallpaper comes up but the installer doesn't.

Comment: This problem is common with earlier Groovy 20.10 installs. I understand that it has been fixed in later dailies. 20.10 is currently beyond the scope of Ask Ubuntu. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1886148

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is common with earlier Groovy 20.10 installs. I understand that it has been fixed in later dailies. 20.10 is currently beyond the scope of Ask Ubuntu. See bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage

(Someone commented this instead of putting an answer so i did it)

Comment: It was posted as a comment and not an answer because it is not a sufficient enough of an answer, and the commenter probably knew that. E.g.: this problem impacts the 20.04 installer too, furthermore the installed OS as well. And 20.04 is within the scope of this site.